# actionscript 3.0 How to pass event as variable in addEventListener

Tags: actionscript-3, events

I want to pass `Event.type` in a variable to `EventDispatcher` like this:

```
public var e:String = "Event.ENTER_FRAME";
addEventListener(e, moveBox);
```

Instead of:

```
addEventListener(event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBox);
```

It is compiling okay but while running the `Event` is not dispatching. Is there anything I am doing wrong, please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The event constants are just strings. For example [`Event.ENTER_FRAME = "enterFrame"`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#ENTER_FRAME). So just make your variable the correct event type string, which you can get from the event constant or an existing event or anywhere else, as long as its the right string.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this:

```
public var e:String = "Event.ENTER_FRAME";
```

do this:

```
public var e:String = Event.ENTER_FRAME;
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, BotMaster,

I changed it to 

e:String = "enterFrame";
addEventListener(e, f);

and it worked. I would be able to pass Events and Functions to EventDispatcher through variables. This means a lot.

thanks a lot